# Generic argument and type for generics in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have defined a type that is generic enough to be used in my definition file. The type is setup as:

```js
type Callback<T> = (err?: Error, response?: T) => void;
```

Usage:

```js
findOneItem(
  param1: string,
  callback: Callback<string>
)

addNewItem(
  item: object,
  callback: Callback<string>
)
```

I'd like to add more than just the type in the callback, I'd like to add the property name, ie. I could achieve the same without generics

```js
addNewItem(
  item: object,
  callback: (err: Error, newItemId: string) => void;
)
```

I think what I'd like to find out is if there is a way to define a custom property name as well as custom type in the Callback type? Or if there is another feature we can use to achieve this without having to type all callbacks for each definition?

ps. feel free to edit the title of question to a more descriptive version of it

Comment: I don't thinks that's possible with the features we have in TypeScript today.

Comment: What do you mean by "property name"?  What property?

Comment: @jcalz Ideally, I'd like to do something like `callback: Callback<[newItemId: string]>`

Comment: Do you mean “function parameter name”?    If so the type system doesn’t really care much about names of function parameters.  There might be *something* you can do but it might not be pretty.